# Using the Web Service client in a multithreaded application

Tags: .net, web-services, soap

We have an application that sends in multiple threads queries to SOAP-service. We sweep that with increase the number of threads execution time of each request increases by an order. To understand why, we wrote a SOAP-extension - as a result it became clear that even with 5 streams of 16-processor server, serialization time is about 95% of the time of the request, with 10 threads did not wait for the query (time for query in 1 thread is about 150ms). 
Who encountered such behavior? It is suspected that in web-service, or within the serializer having a "dead" block. 

P.S. On each thread creates its own instance of the web-service.

 
P.P.S. To deserialize the number of threads does not seem to affect.

Comment: Are you using "Add Web Reference"? Don't do that. Use "Add Service Reference" to use a more modern web service client stack. Also, if you're writing the services, write them in WCF and you get to use binary over TCP/IP in addition to SOAP.

Comment: Servcies already exists and we can't rewrite it to WCF. Have you experienced this problem? You solved this problem?

Comment: The solution is to use WCF. The XML Serializer is simply not efficient. The best you can do is to pre-generate the serialization classes (with sgen.exe), but that only helps the startup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to use WCF.

The XML Serializer is simply not efficient. The best you can do is to pre-generate the serialization classes (with sgen.exe), but that only helps the startup.

The DataContractSerializer is much more efficient. It limits the complexity of the XML, using elements instead of attributes, for instance. The result is fast serialization and deserialization, and the ability to output the XML as text or binary.